# Raycasting Layermask vs RaycastAll

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Hi I have a small question on how the raycasting with layermasks work vs using RaycastAll.

I am trying to project my rays from inside my object and layermask the rays to collide with the same layer as the original object, therefore i need to ignore the "hit" on the original object  itself.

My question is: when Raycasting uses a layermask does it register a collision with other undesirable layers too and then simply ignore them, or does it not even register a collision with those layers in the first place? Would it be worse or equal on performance if I used RaycastAll to logically decide to respond to a layer or not vs somehow using strictly layermasks? Or is it not even an appreciable difference?

I know some posts say that "if you cast it from inside the object it wont collide with that object" but evidently it does.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [official Unity's physics preformance tutorial](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-best-practices). To start with, Raycast is rather cheap operation but it's performance really depends on how you actually do Raycasting. For example, for one of your questions - RaycastAll is more expensive than doing Raycast on a separate layer, it's also mentioned in the link above. It's based on how actually physics work. Unity doesn't implement physics itself, instead it uses existing solutions (like PhysiX for 3d, and earlier it was Box2d for 2d physics).

Also the length of your ray actually influences Raycast's performance. The shorter ray you cast the better performance you get. The worst case is Raycasting to infinity. Another case is that Collider.Raycast is cheaper than Physics.Raycast.

It's no secret, that there is nothing more that some bunch of math equations behind physics in game development so you may thing in such things - the simplier equation you have, the better performance and time to complete you get. So Raycast can be treated as system of equations where you have the equation of the line (actual Raycast) and some number of equations, which describe some 2d/3d object in plane/space and the task is two calculate the points of intersection between your line (Ray) and other objects.

If you don't have complex physics in your game you may not see the difference between RaycastAll and Raycast with layermask, or shorter ray's length, but performance really differs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I honestly don't think i would notice a performance difference because the physics are incredibly simple in my game but I plan to have a lot of objects with the raycast scripting running at once (nothing too extreme) and i like to do things the right way. But that begs a follow up question: How can i have my raycast ignore the collider its emitting from (2D) and still collide with the adjacent objects when everything is of the same layer in the most efficient way possible? (assuming RaycastAll is not the best choice)

Comment: For example, if you cast a ray inside the script, attached to the object you want to ignore one of the simpliest solution is when you get an object in RaycastHit, you can just compare it to the object itself. But it really depends on how you organise objects in your game. Maybe you can set object to a separate layer, or cast ray from different z coordinate (yes it influences raycast in 2d)